# Open vCard file in contacts app from browser Android

Tags: javascript, android, vcf-vcard

I want my users to be able to save a contact by clicking a button. I've learned that this can be done using vCard files.

I generate a vCard file and let the user download it by clicking a button.

On IOS, this works really well, where the contents of the vCard file get shown in the contacts app. The user can simply click "add" and the contact gets saved.

On Android, the same button causes the file to be downloaded as a usual file. The user then clicks open and gets presented with an interface on where he wants to store his file in. The whole process has a much worse UX.

Is it possible to have contact saving on Android in the same way as in IOS?

This is how I cause the download to happen:

```
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/vcard;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(vcard.toString()));
element.setAttribute('download', "contact.vcf");
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element)
```

I tried the intent API syntax like this:

```
element.setAttribute('href', 'intent://vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact/#Intent;action=android.intent.action.INSERT;S.email=hello@world.com;S.phone=+1-212-555-1234end;');
```

That doesn't work either

I found a few other unanswered stack overflow questions from almost a decade ago. I am hoping that Android made some changes that made this possible.

Comment: IMO, it is the nature of Android OS. It considers `.vcf` file as unknown and after downloading, OS determines what app to be used to open the file.

Comment: Is there no way to indicate to Android OS that the .vcf file should be handled in a special way?

Comment: I do not think so!

Comment: @LukasSlezeviciusdid you ever resolve this issue?